# how to create multiple query in one. when i want fetch date from database which is search from user

Tags: php, html, mysqli

here my html code.
i want fetch data from database. when a user search profile then i want display only searched data which enter in form.
the problem is query doesn't work. can you tell me can we run multiple query in single query.

```
  <form method="get" action="search.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   <div class="form_but1">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-lable1" for="sex">Gender : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7 form_radios">
      <div class="select-block1">
        <select name="gender">
            <option value="">Select Gender</option>
            <option value="">Male</option>
            <option value="">Female</option>
        </select>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_but1">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-lable1" for="sex">Marital Status : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7 form_radios">
        <div class="select-block1">
        <select name="mstatus">
            <option>Select status</option>
            <option value="Single">Single</option>
            <option value="Married">Married</option>
            <option value="Widow">Widow</option>
            <option value="Widower">Widower</option>
            <option value="Divorcee">Divorcee</option>
            <option value="Seprated">Seprated</option>
        </select>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_but1">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-lable1" for="sex">Gotra : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7 form_radios">
      <div class="select-block1">
        <select name="gotra">
            <option>Select gotra</option>
            <option value="Aalakuntor">Aalakuntor</option>
            <option value="Bantalor">Bantalor</option>
            <option value="Batalor">Batalor</option>
            <option value="Bayamuttalor">Bayamuttalor</option>

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_but1">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-lable1" for="sex">District / City : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7 form_radios">
      <div class="select-block1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="city" name="city" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_but1">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-lable1" for="sex">Education : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7 form_radios">
        <div class="select-block1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="education" name="education" >
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_but1">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-lable1" for="sex">Age : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7 form_radios">
      <div class="col-sm-5 input-group1">
        <input class="form-control has-dark-background" name="age1" id="slider-name" placeholder="28" type="text" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5 input-group1">
        <input class="form-control has-dark-background" name="age2" id="slider-name" placeholder="40" type="text" >
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_but1">
    <div class="col-sm-5 input-group1">
      <div class="select-block1">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Search" name="search">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>

 </form>
```

here my search.php code.

```
 <div class="paid_people">
   <h1></h1>
   <div class="row_1">
       <?php 
            include("includes/db.php");
            global $con;

            if(isset($_GET['search']))
            {

                $search_gender = $_GET['gender']; 
                $search_mstatus = $_GET['mstatus']; 
                $search_gotra = $_GET['gotra']; 
                $search_city = $_GET['city']; 
                $search_education = $_GET['education']; 
                $search_age1 = $_GET['age1']; 
                $search_age2 = $_GET['age2']; 

                $get_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age BETWEEN '$search_age1' AND '$search_age2' AND gender like '$search_gender' AND mstatus like '$search_mstatus' AND gotra like '$search_gotra' AND education like '$search_education' AND city like'$search_city'";

                $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user);

                while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user))
                {

                    $u_id = $row_user['user_id'];
                    $u_fname = $row_user['first_name'];
                    $u_age = $row_user['age'];
                    $u_education = $row_user['education'];
                    $u_occupation = $row_user['occupation'];
                    $u_city = $row_user['city'];
                    $u_image = $row_user['photo'];
                    $profile_id = $row_user['profile_id'];


                echo "<div class='col-sm-6 paid_people-left'>
                        <ul class='profile_item'>
                        <a href='view_profile.php?userdetail_id=$u_id'>
                        <li class='profile_item-img'>
                            <img src='admin_vadarshadi/users-photo/resized_$u_image' class='img-responsive' alt='$u_fname' />
                        </li>
                        <li class='profile_item-desc'>
                            <h4>Profile ID: $profile_id</h4>
                            <h4>Name: $u_fname &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Age: $u_age Yrs </h4>
                            <p>City: $u_city, Education: $u_education</p>
                            <h5>View Full Profile</h5>
                        </li>
                    <div class='clearfix'> </div>
                        </a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>";

                }

            }
        ?>

   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Whats the problem with the query? Any error or simply no results?

Comment: Could you provide sample data with database table(users) with data type?

Comment: in this page it display all data from user. but i want display which search from users.